# Why was the decision to make a non-traditional prosecutorial judgement unclear at the start of the 2017 Special Counsel Investigation?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government, prosecutorial-discretion, investigation

## Background

One comment on [this question about Robert Mueller's 2017 Special Counsel Investigation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/42887/is-the-premise-of-robert-mueller-about-how-a-sitting-president-cannot-be-indicte) inquired about a specific aspect of the investigation.  This aspect related to the prosecutorial decision making of the Special Counsel:

> First, a traditional prosecution or declination decision entails a binary determination to initiate or decline a prosecution, but we determined not to make a traditional prosecutorial judgment.

This specific portion [seemed to cause a surprised reaction](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2019/04/19/mueller-report-analysis-legal-experts-226662), as well as confusion [given the apparently opposing views on the indictability of a president by federal authorities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROnVadqLoEA).  Knowing the uncertainty about this aspect of federal law, both @Keith McClary, the person who wrote the [original comment prompting this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/42887/17860) and I wondered...

## Question

In the 2017-2019 Special Counsel investigation, why wasn't the initial decision to make a non-traditional prosecutorial judgment made clear at the beginning of the process?

Comment: Presumably the only people who really know the answer to this are Mueller and his staff, and I don't think they've said.